# why spark is dropping rows after sort?

Tags: apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql

I have a except operation on a dataframe.

```
df1.except(df2)
```

The physical plan become a join operation in spark. There is a strange behavior that some rows are dropped after SortMergeJoin. I know that there are problems with joins when the DFs are from the same original DF https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10925 ... So, I convert DF to rdd and back, but it is not solving the problem of dropping rows. 
It is so weird that Spark is dropping rows after sort, just during some Hash Aggregate operation  ... c attached for the dag 
[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can't find it in the docs, but `except` aliases to `subtract` which will return rows that are in df1 but not df2

Comment: how do you know it is dropping rows? any proofs?

Comment: If you look at the DAG, the number of output rows after SortMergeJoin is different with the number of rows in the next two step of the DAG.